# slick.js slider dots disable click but show them anyway

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, slick.js

Is there a way in `slick.js` to show the dots but disable clicking on them?

Showing the dots is in a simple option `dots: true` . By default, the dots can be clicked to navigate through the slide-show. I want to disable this so they'll only be there to look at so you have an idea how far in the slide-show you are.

I tried this

```
$('.slick-dots li button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert();
});
```

The alert does work after click so the selector is right but I think the `preventDefault()` may be overruled somewhere. Is there a nice way to disable this anyway (without hacking it by putting empty elements over the buttons)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can (just by doing small change in your code):-

```
 $('.slick-dots li button').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // use this
});
```

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  autoplay: true,
  dots: true
});

$('.slick-dots li button').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // use this
});
```

```css
.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
    background: green;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
    pointer-events: none
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
     background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css">
 
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick-theme.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.js"></script>

<section class="slider">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Maartje glad to help you.:):)

Answer (score 2):

use css trick `pointer-events: none`

```
.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
    pointer-events: none
}
```

[SampleFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/qxr06tha/)